# Use python script with pymol, via linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, python

I'm trying to run Python scripts `t5.py` that calls in pymol using linux terminal (CLI only), and I'm not too sure why it doesn't work. Below is the message that I got when typing `pymol t5.py` in the command line.

I have pymol installed

```
sourdough@ZT:/mnt/c/Users/AceRe/Desktop$ pymol t5.py
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

The script is shown below.

```
from pymol import cmd
f=open('dist5.txt','w')
r1 = 'r55_01///UNL`1/N*'
r2 = 'r55_01///UNL`1/O*'
r3 = 'r55_01//R/ASP`113/OD2'
r4 = 'r55_01//R/ASN`312/ND2'

d1=cmd.distance(r1,r3,cutoff=5,mode=2)
d2=cmd.distance(r2,r4,cutoff=5,mode=2)

r1 = 'Lig_N'
r2 = 'Lig_O'
r3 = 'D113'
r4 = 'N312'

f.write("%5s %4s %4.2f\n"%(r1,r3,d1))
f.write("%5s %4s %4.2f\n"%(r2,r4,d2))
f.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running this in a graphical terminal locally on your machine, or are you running it remotely via SSH connected to some other system? Are you expecting the program to open a window?

Comment: Are you supposed to run it with `pymol`, and not with `python`?

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda I'm running this on a local terminal on my machine, and it's a CLI only, so I don't really expect, or want pymol to open a new window

Comment: Hey @Panki, from what I read, I'm supposed to run it with pymol